# Import modules in package in ROS2

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, ros2

I have created a package for ROS2 and I have added a Python repository I downloaded. The problem I am having is that in the original repository the modules from the own repo were imported directly while in mine I have to import them adding the ROS2 package name before the module, even though I am importing a module from the same repo, like:

`import planner_pkg.SimpleOneTrailerSystem as SimpleOneTrailerSystem`

while I would like:

`import SimpleOneTrailerSystem`

My ROS2 project structure is like:

```
ros2_ws
  src
    planner
      planner_pkg
        __init__.py
        SimpleOneTrailerSystem.py
        planner_node.py
        ...
      package.xml
      setup.py
```

package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>planner_pkg</name>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <description>This package contains algorithm for park planner</description>

  <maintainer email=""></maintainer>
  <license>Apache License 2.0</license>

  <exec_depend>rclpy</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>

  <!-- These test dependencies are optional
  Their purpose is to make sure that the code passes the linters -->
  <test_depend>ament_copyright</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_flake8</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_pep257</test_depend>
  <test_depend>python3-pytest</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_python</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

package_name = 'planner_pkg'

setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=[package_name],
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
            ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    author='',
    author_email='',
    maintainer='',
    maintainer_email='',
    keywords=['ROS'],
    classifiers=[
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Topic :: Software Development',
    ],
    description='Package containing examples of how to use the rclpy API.',
    license='Apache License, Version 2.0',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'planner_node = planner_pkg.planner_node:main',
        ],
    },
)
```

Comment: Placing external dependencies in your package is not usually recommended. Could you use a tool such as `pip` to install your dependency for you?

Comment: What I mean by external dependency is a module I have developed in another package, not a module developed by another person. It is explained in my question

Answer (score 12):

First, according to the [Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) docs, when you do `import something`, Python looks for that `something` in the following places:

- From the built-in modules
- `sys.path`, which is a `list` containing:

  - The directory of the input script
  - `PYTHONPATH`, which is an environment variable containing a list of directories
  - The installation-dependent default

Second, when you build your ROS2 Python package (by calling `colcon build` invoking the `ament_python` build type), your Python codes will be copied over to an *install* folder with a tree structure like this:

```
install
...
├── planner_pkg
│   ├── bin
│   │   └── planner_node
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── python3.6
│   │       └── site-packages
│   │           ├── planner_pkg
│   │           │   ├── __init__.py
│   │           │   ├── planner_node.py
│   │           │   └── SimpleOneTrailerSystem.py
...
```

Now, when you do `import SimpleOneTrailerSystem`, Python will first search for it from the built-in modules, which for sure it won't find there. Next on the list is from `sys.path`. You can add a `print(sys.path)` at the top of *planner_node.py* to see something like this list:

```
['/path/to/install/planner_pkg/bin', 
 '/path/to/install/planner_pkg/lib/python3.6/site-packages', 
 '/opt/ros/eloquent/lib/python3.6/site-packages', 
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip', 
 '/usr/lib/python3.6', 
 ...other Python3.6 installation-dependent dirs...
]
```

First on the `sys.path` list is the *bin* folder of the input script. There are only executables there, no *SimpleOneTrailerSystem.py* file/module, so that import will fail.

The next on the list would be the *planner_pkg/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages*, and as you can see from the tree structure above, there is a *SimpleOneTrailerSystem.py* module **BUT it is under a *planner_pkg* folder**. So a direct import like this

```
import SimpleOneTrailerSystem
```

will not work. You need to qualify it with the package folder like this:

```
import planner_pkg.SimpleOneTrailerSystem
```

There are 2 ways to get around this.

1. Modify `sys.path` before `import`-ing `SimpleOneTrailerSystem`

   ```py
   import sys
   sys.path.append("/path/to/install/planner_pkg/lib/python3.6/site-packages/planner_pkg")

   import SimpleOneTrailerSystem
   ```

   This approach adds the path to the `planner_pkg` *install* directory to the `sys.path` list so that you don't need to specify it in subsequent imports.
2. Modify `PYTHONPATH` before running your ROS2 node

   ```sh
   $ colcon build
   $ source install/setup.bash
   $ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/install/planner_pkg/lib/python3.6/site-packages/planner_pkg
   $ planner_node
   ```

   This approach is almost the same as the first one, but there is no code change involved (and no rebuilding involved), as you only need to modify the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it by modifying setup.py.

Add:

> ('lib/' + package_name, [package_name+'/SimpleOneTrailerSystem.py']),

to "data_files" list.

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

package_name = 'planner_pkg'

setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=[package_name],
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
            ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
        ('lib/' + package_name, [package_name+'/SimpleOneTrailerSystem.py']),
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    author='',
    author_email='',
    maintainer='',
    maintainer_email='',
    keywords=['ROS'],
    classifiers=[
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Topic :: Software Development',
    ],
    description='Package containing examples of how to use the rclpy API.',
    license='Apache License, Version 2.0',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'planner_node = planner_pkg.planner_node:main',
        ],
    },
)
```

Answer (score -1):

For CMAKE packages with cpp and python code you can add the following lines to your CMakeLists.txt.
This will copy your python_pkg folder into your install environment to "lib/python{version}/site-packages" which is per default included in your python path.

```
# for python code
find_package(ament_cmake_python REQUIRED)
find_package(rclpy REQUIRED)

install(DIRECTORY
    ../path_to_python_pkg
    DESTINATION lib/python3.8/site-packages
)

install(PROGRAMS
    ${PROJECT_NAME}/python_node.py
    DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

ament_python_install_package(${PROJECT_NAME})
```

If you are using e.g. Dashing or Eloquent it is "python3.6", for Foxy or newer it is "python3.8"

Comment: I don't think this is very helpful. OP is writing a Python-only package.